# Can we download multiple files in a Single Coroutine in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-download-manager, ktor

**Hi all Developers pls sort out my query as much as possible.**

I'm working on Image Album application. Here while user click on particular album we should download all related images to that particular album.

For example album name is Tree so that album have multiple image url's array. So i should download all images from that album by array of url's

Ex : imageArray = arrayOf("url1","url2","url3","url4",....etc url(n))

i should put them in for loop or else recursion then i should download them upto (n) urls on completion of one by one.

i have written snippet for one file download here my doubt is how i can proceed to download multiple files.

should i use same coroutine for all files download or else one one coroutine for one one file

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

**//here itself i can run for loop or else any other robust/proper way to do this requirement.**

                ktor.downloadFile(outputStream, url).collect {

                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        when (it) {
                            is DownloadResult.Success -> {
**//on success of one file download should i call recursively to download one more file by this method - private fun downloadFile(context: Context, url: String, file: Uri)**
                                viewFile(file)
                            }
```

**below is the code to download a single file**

```
    private fun downloadFile(context: Context, url: String, file: Uri) {

        val ktor = HttpClient(Android)
        contentResolver.openOutputStream(file)?.let { outputStream ->

            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

                ktor.downloadFile(outputStream, url).collect {

                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        when (it) {
                            is DownloadResult.Success -> {
                                viewFile(file)
                            }

                            is DownloadResult.Error -> {
                            }

                            is DownloadResult.Progress -> {
                                txtProgress.text = "${it.progress}"
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }


suspend fun HttpClient.downloadFile(file: OutputStream, url: String): Flow<DownloadResult> {
    return flow {
        try {
            val response = call {
                url(url)
                method = HttpMethod.Get
            }.response

            val data = ByteArray(response.contentLength()!!.toInt())
            var offset = 0

            do {
                val currentRead = response.content.readAvailable(data, offset, data.size)
                offset += currentRead
                val progress = (offset * 100f / data.size).roundToInt()
                emit(DownloadResult.Progress(progress))
            } while (currentRead > 0)

            response.close()

            if (response.status.isSuccess()) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    file.write(data)
                }
                emit(DownloadResult.Success)
            } else {
                emit(DownloadResult.Error("File not downloaded"))
            }
        } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
            emit(DownloadResult.Error("Connection timed out", e))
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            emit(DownloadResult.Error("Failed to connect"))
        }
    }
}

sealed class DownloadResult {
    object Success : DownloadResult()

    data class Error(val message: String, val cause: Exception? = null) : DownloadResult()

    data class Progress(val progress: Int): DownloadResult()
}
```

Gradle Files i have used

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3'
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.2.5"
```

Comment: the method call is deprecated. and blocks the response until it is fully received. you won't be able to get real-time progress

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible.

1. Create another function that will iterate through the list of files to be downloaded.
2. With the new function, use an *async* or *launch* coroutine function - this allows for more control over the flow of your logic, sequential behavior or asynchronous behavior respectively.

e.g. `fun downloadBatch(list: List<Uri>) { GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { //logic goes here }}`

**Note**: GlobalScope is just for an easy example - not advisable to use in live production.

3. Inside the iterator/for-loop, call a function to download an individual file. This particular function should be appended with *suspend* at the beginning
   e.g. `suspend fun downloadFile(uri: Uri)`

**Note**: the suspended function won't use any threading logic itself and depends on being nested within a functional Coroutine.

4. Continue to use rxJava, or try LiveData, to broadcast your files.

Comment: A very astute explanation for batch file download. @OP do try this once and let us know if you need any further suggestions

Comment: @zuko can i use workmanager here instead of service to continuous download of multiple files because if user closes application also download should run and complete i thought to go with foreground service but any possibilities to use workmanager concept like i can add 100 download urls to workmanager and let it download pls give me your suggestions.

Comment: It really just comes down to your needs for the app, and the type of experience you want the user to have. https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/build-for-billions/connectivity - I think this article provides a pretty insightful explanation of offline-first architecture, and should provide you with enough info to get going. Another thing to think about is how important are these files to the application? The more critical, the faster you'll want them to be fetched.